# Summation over multiple rows based on a condition in R

Tags: r, group-by, mutated

I have a dataset like the following

| name | city | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | M | 2 |
| A | N | 3 |
| A | O | 5 |
| A | P | 7 |
| B | M | 7 |
| B | N | 8 |
| B | 0 | 9 |
| B | P | 2 |

For each of of the name category, I want to sum the number of M and N value and put it in a new variable. The same goes for O and P value.
The dataset should look like the following:

| name | city | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 5 |
| A | Y | 12 |
| B | X | 15 |
| B | Y | 11 |

I'm new in R programming. I have tried to use group by and mutate method but was not successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could modify the values in the column 'city' to 'X', 'Y', and do a group by sum

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(name, city = case_when(city %in% c("M", "N") ~ 'X',
    city %in% c("O", "P") ~ "Y")) %>%
   summarise(number = sum(number), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  name  city  number
  <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 A     X          5
2 A     Y         12
3 B     X         15
4 B     Y         11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), city = c("M", "N", "O", "P", "M", "N", "O", "P"), number = c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It works perfectly!  Neat and clean solution!